# Upload AJAX selecionar multiplos arquivos

Tags: javascript, ajax

Este script abaixo seleciona para UPLOAD apenas um arquivo. Fiz diversas pesquisas e não encontrei nada que pudesse implementar para que eu conseguisse selecionar múltiplos arquivos.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function(){
        var btnUpload=$('#upload');
        var status=$('#status');
        new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
            // Arquivo que fará o upload
            action: 'upload-file.php',
            //Nome da caixa de entrada do arquivo
            name: 'uploadfile',
            onSubmit: function(file, ext){
                 if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))){ 
                    // verificar a extensão de arquivo válido
                    status.text('Somente JPG, PNG ou GIF são permitidas');
                    return false;
                }
                status.text('Enviando...');
            },
            onComplete: function(file, response){
                //Limpamos o status
                status.text('');
                //Adicionar arquivo carregado na lista
                if(response==="success"){
                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').html('<img src="./uploads/'+file+'" alt="" /><br />'+file).addClass('success');
                } else{
                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('#files').text(file).addClass('error');
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Alguém sabe me ajudar nesta questão?

Comment: Esse `btnUpload=$('#upload')` é o botão de submit do form?

Comment: sim, isso mesmo!

Comment: O input file vc tem ai?

Comment: Pelo que sei a implementação deve estar neste trecho: new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
   // Arquivo que fará o upload
   action: 'upload-file.php',
   //Nome da caixa de entrada do arquivo
   name: 'uploadfile',
   multiple: 'true',

Tentei colocar a opção: multiple: 'true'. Mas sem sucesso!

Comment: [Olhe esse plugin:](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html), talvez seja bem completo e pode adiantar teu trabalho.

Answer (score 4):

Para fazer upload de multiplos ficheiros é preciso ter em conta alguns aspetos.

- tens um input `multiple` para todos os ficheiro ou inputs diferentes para cada ficheiro?
- queres fazer o upload em série ou concorrente (sequêncial)?

## Múltiplos inputs, 1 ficheiro por input

No caso de serem múltiplos ficheiros **mas cada um com o seu input** nesse caso é simples, e só tens de criar um loop no teu código.

#### envios concorrentes:

```
var inputs = $('.inputs');
var status = $('#status');
inputs.get().forEach(function(input, i) {
    // aqui podes usar o "i" se só quiseres saber o numero
    // eu vou usar o nome do ficheiro
    var ficheiro = input.files[0];
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload-file.php',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: (new FormData()).append('file', ficheiro),
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6pj5ckra/4/

Neste caso ele dispara em imediato pedidos paralelos (concorrentes). É a forma mais rápida.

#### envios em série, consecutivos::

```
var inputs = $('.inputs').get();
var status = $('#status');

function proximoAjax() {
    var proximo = inputs.shift();
    var data = (new FormData()).append('file', proximo.files[0])
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload-file.php',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function(file, ext) {
            // etc...
        },
        success: function(file, response) {
            proximoAjax(); // <----
            // etc...
        }
    });
}
proximoAjax();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dq8Ldohr/5/

## Input unico, com atributo `multiple`, *n* ficheiros por input

#### envios concorrentes:

```
var input = $('#input');
var status = $('#status');
var ficheiros = input.get().map(function(input, i) {
    returninput.files[i];
});
ficheiros.forEach(function(ficheiro) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload-file.php',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: (new FormData()).append('file', ficheiro),
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6pj5ckra/3/

#### envios em série, consecutivos:

```
var input = $('#input');
var status = $('#status');
var ficheiros = input.get().map(function(input, i) {
    returninput.files[i];
});
function proximoAjax() {
    var proximo = ficheiros.shift();
    var data = (new FormData()).append('file', proximo)
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload-file.php',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function(file, ext) {
            // etc...
        },
        success: function(file, response) {
            proximoAjax(); // <----
            // etc...
        }
    });
}
proximoAjax();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dq8Ldohr/4/

---

### Notas:

#### #1

Esta resposta aponta as diferenças e possibilidades. Não testei exatamente o teu código pois não tenho acesso a ele. Desta maneira, usando o `$.ajax` do jQuery e não a tua abstração `new AjaxUpload()` acho que fica também mais fácil de manter, e util a outros que como eu não sabem o que essa `new AjaxUpload()` faz.

#### #2

Quando uso o `.get()` é para converter um objeto jQuery numa *Array* nativa. Mais fácil de trabalhar e saber como usar o resultado a meu ver.

#### #3

A principal diferênça num input simples `<input type="file" />` e um input que aceita múltiplos ficheiros `<input type="file" multiple />` é (para além do atributo `multiple`) que a propriedade `.files` do elemento têm os nomes guardados. Ou seja, um input simples só tem `.files[0]`  enquanto que um input `multiple` têm `.files[0]`, `.files[1]`, etc...

Comment: acredito que uma opção para realizar um envio unico é ter todos os `input[type='file']` dentro de um `form#formID` e usar `var formID = document.getElementById('formID'); new FormData(formID)`... no mais o `$.ajax` usa por padrão o contentType `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` enquanto que para se enviar um FormData o content type deve ser o `multipart/form-data`, então acredito que deva setar `processData: false` e `contentType: false,` nas opções do `$.ajax`... no mais a sua resposta merece um `+2`.

Comment: @TobyMosque obrigado, juntei `processData` e `contentType ` no objeto passado ao ajax.

Comment: @Sergio fiz a implementação do terceiro código https://jsfiddle.net/6pj5ckra/3/ que vc postou porém não funcionou. Teria como vc implementá-lo no código que tenho acima? Porque com certeza eu fiz de forma errada esta implementação.

Comment: @GladisonNeuzaPerosini pois há lógica errada aí. Queres enviar os ficheiros quando? há um botão para enviar ou assim que os ficheiros forem selecionados?

Comment: @Sergio atualmente meu código funciona quando o arquivo é selecionado. Já que o código seleciona apenas um para cada envio. Gostaria de manter este estilo. Apenas implementar para que eu possa selecionar e enviar vários de uma única vez.

Comment: @Sergio tem como me orientar nesta implementação?

Comment: @GladisonNeuzaPerosini então queres correr o ajax quando houver o evento `change` desse input por exemplo?

Comment: @Sergio sim, isso.